# Maximum characters query “Query/Where windows pops up”

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

By default what is the maximum characters query length in “Query/Where windows pops up” in oracle form, and how can we increase them.

Comment: Is this a question about Oracle Forms?  If so (a) what version? (b) do you mean the WHERE clause editor in the Forms Builder, or the popup at runtime when the user puts a colon in the field and presses Execute Q
uery?

Comment: Yes, this question is about oracle form Version 6.0.8.11.3. When user puts a colon in the field and presses Execute Query.

Answer (score 0):

Maximum length of an Oracle block's WHERE clause is 32,000 bytes. You cannot increase this limit. Generally, if your where clause is greater than 1,000 characters, you would look at an alternative design for how your form works.